# Mapping Keys to Commands in Vimperator

Tags: firefox, keyboard, fedora, remapping, vimperator

I want to close the current tab on clicking `ww` that is two minuscule **w**'s sequentially

So I imagine I need to put in `vimperatorrc` a line similar to the following

```
map <ww> :tabclose<CR>
```

but it doesn't work

So, how can I accomplish that?

Comment: "it doesn't work" > Can you confirm what happens instead? Do you get `:winopen` prompt? Is that something you'd be OK to lose?

Comment: Yes, it seems to be mapped to `winopen` by default, I'd like to remap `winopen`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this in your `.vimperatorrc`:

```
map ww :tabclose<CR>
```

The trick is to remove the `<>` around the `ww`. I spotted the problem by typing `:map` and seeing the offered completions which included the leading `<` - which didn't make sense.

Comment: That's great, thank you, I accepted the answer, but I am also wondering if there's a way to tell Vimperator to differentiate between a click and double click  keeping the default `w` map for `:winopen` as well.

Comment: Thanks for the upvote and accept :D ... the issue with having both `w` and `ww` active as mappings is finding a way to help Vimperator distinguish between `w` as the start of `ww` and the request for `w`. Maybe experiment with putting a new `w<Space>` mapping for win open?